# My program won't display numerical values correctly

Tags: .net, vb.net, decimal

My program is supposed to calculate the cost of items, when it runs it won't display decimals. For example if a user entered 5.99 in the cost text box, and 5 in the number of items box, 25 will be showed as the output.

```
Public Class Form1
Private Sub btnCalculate_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnCalculate.Click
    Dim DecCost As Decimal = txtCost.Text
    Dim intNumber As Integer = txtNumber.Text
    If Decimal.TryParse(txtNumber.Text, DecCost) Then
        Dim DecTotal As Decimal = intNumber * DecCost
        lblTotal.Text = DecTotal
    Else
        lblTotal.Text = "Please Enter Numerals in Both Boxes."
    End If

End Sub
```

End Class

Thanks in advance!

*EDIT* I just tried some new values in the text boxes at runtime.
It seems to multiplying the Number of items value by itself.
I have no-idea why...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the issue is that you're parsing `txtNumber.Text` and storing it in `DecCost`, which you're already using to hold the cost.  You'll need a `DecCost` Decimal, to store the cost, and an `intNumber` integer to store the quantity.  Then, parse each text box and multiple the results together.

```
Dim decCost As Decimal
Dim intNumber As Integer
If Integer.TryParse(txtNumber.Text, intNumber) AND Decimal.TryParse(txtCost.Text, decCost) Then
    lblTotal.Text = decCost * intNumber
Else
    lblTotal.Text = "Please Enter Numerals in Both Boxes."
End If
```

[Demo](http://ideone.com/DUFsjI)

Comment: I'm not sure what you're trying to do with `txtNumber.Text * DecCost` (a string times a decimal).  Are you trying to square the number?  Why not just `DecCost * DecCost` then?

Comment: I'm trying to get the total cost of some items, I'll try creating two variables and see if that fixes anything.

Comment: Then why are you parsing `txtNumber.Text` and storing it again as `DecCost`?

Comment: I see what you're saying now, it's an issue with my try parse.

Comment: It's fixed now, I'm pretty new to coding, this was an assignment for my class and I was having issues, I couldnt ask my teacher because it's an online class and he wouldnt respond till monday. Thanks A lot!

Comment: No problem, I haven't done any VB in years so I'm a little rusty on the syntax.  Good luck on your assignment!